# Как можно записать в одну строку скрипт на Python?

Tags: python

Есть код:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('192.168.0.195', 6969))

with open('hello.txt', "rb") as f:
    buffer = f.read(4096)
    while buffer:
        s.sendall(buffer)
        buffer = f.read(4096)

s.close()
```

Возможно ли его записать в одну строку (через ;), чтобы можно было исполнить через `python -c '...'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Можно закодировать текст кода в base64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13358451/5909792), после через `eval` его выполнить.

Сделаю пример, а вы сами в `code` поместите ваш код

Пример:

```
import base64

code = '''\
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
print('Finish!')
'''

code = base64.b64encode(code.encode('utf-8'))
print(code)
# b'Zm9yIGkgaW4gcmFuZ2UoNSk6CiAgICBwcmludChpKQpwcmludCgnRmluaXNoIScpCg=='

# Выполнять так:
# eval(compile(base64.b64decode(code), '<string>', 'exec'))
```

Теперь в консоли:

```
> python -c "import base64; code = b'Zm9yIGkgaW4gcmFuZ2UoNSk6CiAgICBwcmludChpKQpwcmludCgnRmluaXNoIScpCg==';
eval(compile(base64.b64decode(code), '<string>', 'exec'))"                                                                 
0                                                                                                                           
1                                                                                                                           
2                                                                                                                           
3                                                                                                                           
4                                                                                                                           
Finish!
```

Comment: Спасибо, почему-то не пришло в голову такое решение, хотя о base64 знал

Answer (score 2):

Да, можно. Вот короткий пример:

```
echo -e "import sys\nfor r in range(10): print 'rob'" | python
```

или

```
python -c "exec(\"import sys\nfor r in range(10): print 'rob'\")"
```

или

```
(echo "import sys" ; echo "for r in range(10): print 'rob'") | python
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043453/executing-multi-line-statements-in-the-one-line-command-line)

Обратите внимание в примере на цикл **for** (у Вас также вложенные **with** и **while**).

Answer (score 0):

Как верно заметили выше, можно завернуть весь текст в одну строку с сохранением табуляций и подсунуть это функции [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), заменив все переносы на `\n`, а каждый отступ на `\t`:

```
exec("""import socket\ns = socket.socket()\ns.connect(('192.168.0.195', 6969))\nwith open('hello.txt', "rb") as f:\n\tbuffer = f.read(4096)\n\twhile buffer:\n\t\ts.sendall(buffer)\n\t\tbuffer = f.read(4096)\ns.close()""")
```

Но также записывать выражения в одну строчку позволяет точка с запятой, но у такого подхода есть существенное ограничение на вложенные блоки, поэтому фрагменты с `with` и `while` придётся переписать.

Для данного случая можно переделать цикл до конца файла поблоковым циклом с вычислением размера файла:

```
import socket
import os
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('192.168.0.195', 6969))
filename = 'hello.txt'
f = open(filename, "rb") # не используем with
sz = os.path.getsize(filename) # получаем размер файла в байтах
part = 4096
gen = (f.read(part) for i in range(sz // part + 1)) # генератор для получения новой порции
[s.sendall(buffer) for buffer in gen] # используем генератор для цикла 
f.close() 
s.close()
```

Или в одну строчку:

```
import socket;import os;s = socket.socket();s.connect(('192.168.0.195', 6969));filename = 'hello.txt';f = open(filename, "rb");sz = os.path.getsize(filename);part = 4096;gen = (f.read(part) for i in range(sz // part + 1));[s.sendall(buffer) for buffer in gen];f.close();s.close()
```

Одну строчку читать всё равно тяжело, но её может развернуть IDE стандартными средствами оформления